# Jar utility for the Java package org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*

Tags: spring, hibernate, excel, jar, oracle10g

I'm working with Spring/Hibernate (using NetBeans 6.9.1). I need to import Excel sheet into Oracle database (10g).

I have visited some articles and tutorials like this [one](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSP-Servlet/19076-How-to-export-web-page-to-excel-using-java-or-jsp-or-servlets.html) in which I found the appropriate code to do so but the Jar utility containing the Java package `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*` which is needed for this functionality to perform has not been mentioned in any of these tutorials I have found on the internet. So only one question...

From where can I download this Jar utility containing this package `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*`?

This package contains Java classes like

```
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;  
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook; 
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [FindJar](http://www.findjar.com) service to find a jar containing a class.

In you case, you can find the results here : http://www.findjar.com/class/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html